# How can I resize Arc in highcharts?

Tags: highcharts, renderer

My goal is to draw a curved line with arrows on both ends.
I am trying to recreate the curved dotted line/arrows at the bottom of this graphic.

https://www.epa.gov/sites/production/files/2019-07/active_cases_under_review-7_1_19-boxes.png

So far I have a curved line (originally an arc) that needs to be smaller.

I've various sizing for attributes and css nothing has worked.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 300px"></div>
```

---

```
var renderer;

renderer = new Highcharts.Renderer(
    $('#container')[0],
    400,
    300
);

renderer.arc(200, 150, -100, -100, -Math.PI, 0)
.attr({
    stroke: '#D3D3D3',
    'stroke-width': 2,
    dashstyle: 'dash'
        })
.add();
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a curved line with arrows on both ends it will be better to use a combination of `renderer.path` and  `renderer.symbol('triangle')`. I've created an example for you with horizontal arrows, test it and change the way it works as you like.

```js
var arrWidth = 14,
 arrHeight = 25,
  startX = 80,
  startY = 200,
  endX = 200,
  endY = 100,
  renderer;

renderer = new Highcharts.Renderer(
  $('#container')[0],
  800,
  800
);

renderer.symbol('triangle', startX - arrWidth/2, startY - arrHeight, arrWidth, arrHeight)
.attr({
  fill: '#D3D3D3',
  rotation: -90,
  rotationOriginX: startX,
  rotationOriginY: startY
}).add();

renderer.symbol('triangle', endX - arrWidth/2, endY - arrHeight, arrWidth, arrHeight)
.attr({
  fill: '#D3D3D3',
  rotation: 90,
  rotationOriginX: endX,
  rotationOriginY: endY
}).add();

renderer.path([
 'M',
  startX,
  startY,
  'C',
  (startX + endX) / 2,
  startY,
  (startX + endX) / 2,
  endY,
  endX,
  endY
]).attr({
 stroke: '#D3D3D3',
  'stroke-width': 2,
  dashstyle: 'dash'
}).add();
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 300px"></div>
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/prz5w9ox/1/

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#path
- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#symbol
- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SymbolDictionary

Comment: Almost got it.  It's on my page.  Issue with moving the lines in left/right direction (x axis).  The lines lose shape, the curve and arrow gets out of wack.

Comment: Could you send an example?

Comment: I'm not sure which numbers to manipulate in order to move them to a different part of the page.

Comment: I showed you just an example of the implementation. It is not a generic solution, so you have to play with arrows rotation, change the curve control points, etc.